# returning int with int*

Tags: c++, pointers, return-type

```
class A {
  private:
    int* count = NULL;
  public:
    A() {
      count = NULL;
    }
    int getCount() {
      return *count;
    }
};
```

There is a simple problem in returning `int` type with my `int*` type variable. When I write `A a();` and run `a.getCount();` it gives me segmentation fault. But I don't understand why. Am I misunderstanding the concept of pointer..?

Comment: What exactly did you expect to get by dereferencing a null pointer?

Comment: I expected to get 0.

Comment: But if `int *count = NULL;` then `*count` doesn't give `0` as you are dereferencing `NULL` pointer. I think you might want like `if(count == NULL) { count = new int; *count = 10; }`

Comment: Why is `count` a pointer ?  Is there any reason it can't be an `int` ?

Comment: @Achal Oh okay. I thought when I dereference a `NULL` pointer, I would automatically get `0` but that wasn't the case. Thanks! I've solved my problem!

Comment: An `int` pointer has to point at a valid `int` in order to be dereferenceable. Dereferencing gets the value pointed at, If the pointer doesn't point at anything, there is no value to get and Undefined behaviour occurs. Most systems these days mark off the first few hundred (or thousand) bytes as untouchable so that you can catch null pointers easily. Pointers that point at something invalid that's not null can get you in a lot of trouble and can be very hard to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting a segmentation fault at `return *count;`. **Why?**. This is because you are trying to de-reference a pointer variable (`*count;`) whose value is still `NULL` (not pointing to anything);

You should re-write

```
int getCount() 
{
   return *count;
}
```

as

```
int getCount() 
{
   if (count != NULL)
      return *count;
   return 0; // 0 or -1 other any other value depends on your code logic.
}
```

In a different way you can also initialize the value of `count` in constructor to some `value`.

```
A() 
{
   *count = 0; // 0 or -1 other any other value depends on your code logic.
}
```

Comment: Oh that was why I was getting the seg fault. Thanks! Your words really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a pointer point to something before you can dereference it.